# How do I check if I've been run in read-only mode (-R) in vimrc

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc, I'd like to be able to check if I've been run either by `vim -R` or `view`. If so, I plan to either disable or delay some plugins from loading to speed up the times when I quickly want to look at a file.

`:args` and `argv()` only seem to show me which files I wanted to edit, not all the command line flags.

Checking `if &readonly` almost works. If I have this:

```
if &readonly
    echo "read only"
else
    echo "not read only"
endif
```

Then I get `read only` echoed when I execute `view` or `vim -R`, but if I do either `view ~/.vimrc` or `vim -R ~/.vimrc` then I get `not read only`. Very strange.

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem.  Try to save your `if` in a new file (say, `test_readonly.vim`) and run `view -u test_readonly.vim -R ~/.vimrc` to see that no plugins interfere. Note that `:w!` will deactivate `readonly`, so if any of your plugins do that, that's the reason.

Comment: @Amadan I did exactly what described and still observe the same behavior. Both `vim -u test_readonly.vim ~/.vimrc` and `view -u test_readonly.vim ~/.vimrc` echo `not read only`. Running those same commands *without* a file to edit returns `not read only` and `read only`, respectively. `test_readonly.vim` is simply that if statement I listed above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&readonly` setting is local to a buffer, and isn't set until a buffer is loaded. Your vimrc file is parsed *before* any buffer are loaded.

Consider what would happen if you would type `vim -o /etc/passwd ~/readable`. One buffer will be readonly, and the other won't be. Should this setting be on or off?

So you'll need to hook into the [`BufReadPost`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufReadPost) autocommand, which is executed after reading a file into a buffer:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *
    \  if &readonly
    \|  echo "read only"
    \| else
    \|  echo "not read only"
    \| endif
```

Which should give the expected results.

Note that this will run *every time* a buffer is loaded. If you just want to show it once, you'll need to remove this autocommand when it's run. This can be done with an autocommand group; `autocommand! <group_name>` will remove all autocommands in a group.

```
augroup readonly
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufReadPost *
        \  if &readonly
        \|  echom "read only"
        \| else
        \|  echom "not read only"
        \| endif
        \| autocmd! readonly
augroup end
```

Comment: Yep, this makes perfect sense. I understand `readonly` is buffer local, but I was hoping it had special meaning when my `.vimrc` was loading. I'm currently trying to get your answer merged with [this](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/faq#loading-plugins-manually) but having some difficulties. I'll keep playing around with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Vim's program name (eg `view`) can be detected with the `v:progname` variable. This doesn't solve checking for `vim -R`, but it does allow you to use this variable in a condition in your `.vimrc` and potentially improve the efficiency of your config.  For example:

```
if v:progname ==? 'view'
  " Do something
endif
```